# RadRotator not flowing smoothly

Tags: c#, telerik, radrotator

I'm doing a simple radrotator program. Function :

- Add multiple images to radrotator dynamically.
- Assign button to navigate RadRotator to desirable image using **GoTo** function.

My problem is :

- I cannot insert multiple images. Only one image.
- the radrotator showing a frame of image and next fram is a blank frame.

This is my coding:

```
Public partial class Station : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    public Station()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Station_Load;
        this.radPanoramaFrom.PanoramaElement.DragDropService.PreviewDragOver += PreviewDragOver;
        this.radPanoramaDestination.PanoramaElement.DragDropService.PreviewDragOver += PreviewDragOver;
    }

    public void addItemsRotator()
    {
        RadItemsContainer imageItemContainer = new RadItemsContainer();
        this.radRotatorFrom.Items.Add(imageItemContainer);

        RadItemsContainer emptyContainer = new RadItemsContainer();
        this.radRotatorFrom.Items.Add(emptyContainer);

        RadImageItem imageItem = new RadImageItem();
        imageItem.Image = Properties.Resources.access;
        imageItem.StretchHorizontally = false;
        imageItem.StretchVertically = false;
        imageItem.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        imageItemContainer.Items.Add(imageItem);

        RadImageItem imageItem1 = new RadImageItem();
        imageItem1.Image = Properties.Resources.word;
        imageItem1.StretchHorizontally = false;
        imageItem1.StretchVertically = false;
        imageItem1.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        imageItemContainer.Items.Add(imageItem1);
    } 

   private void Station_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addItemsRotator();
    }
```

Comment: Look carefully at your variable names: it looks like you defined `imageItem1` and then set properties on `imageItem` by mistake. Also take a look at [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx), which would make it unnecessary to retype `imageItem1` for each property you're setting.

Comment: change to imageitem1 already. that is not the problem here. Thanks btw ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the way:

for 1st problem:

I have to create multiple object for each radelement.

```
        RadImageItem one = new RadImageItem();
        one.Image = Properties.Resources.one;
        one.StretchHorizontally = false;
        one.StretchVertically = false;
        one.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        radRotatorFrom.Items.Add(one);

        RadImageItem oneCopy = new RadImageItem();
        oneCopy.Image = Properties.Resources.one;
        oneCopy.StretchHorizontally = false;
        oneCopy.StretchVertically = false;
        oneCopy.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        radRotatorDestination.Items.Add(oneCopy);
```

for 2nd problem :

I have to remove this codes,

```
    RadItemsContainer imageItemContainer = new RadItemsContainer();
    this.radRotatorFrom.Items.Add(imageItemContainer);

    RadItemsContainer emptyContainer = new RadItemsContainer();
    this.radRotatorFrom.Items.Add(emptyContainer);
```